# Reduce big O notation for faster runtime, now it doesnt execute because it is too long, anyone know a solution?

Tags: c++

The code below is to calculate the exponential growth of fish.
How can I reduce this to O(N) for a capable runtime? Now my code is O(N2) and it wont execute because it will take too long. Any suggestions?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <numeric>


void CalculateNewFish(std::vector <int64_t>& NewValues, int Days) {
    if (Days == 256) {
        std::cout << "Day " << Days << ": " << NewValues.size()<< std::endl;
    }
    else if(Days >= 0) {
        for (int l = 0; l < NewValues.size(); ++l) {
            NewValues.at(l)--;
            if(NewValues.at(l) < 0) {
                NewValues.at(l) = 6;
                NewValues.push_back(9);
            }
        } 
        CalculateNewFish(NewValues, Days + 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream myfile;
    int a;
    std::vector <int64_t> Values;
    myfile.open("inputday6.txt");
    while (myfile >> a) {
        Values.push_back(a);
    }
    myfile.close();
    CalculateNewFish(Values, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason (homework requirements, etc) that you're using recursion instead of a for loop to iterate the days?

Comment: You probably don't need a (growing) vector. A frequency map seems more appropriate. and computation could be done without simulation with some math.

Comment: Hint: the contribution of every initial entry of `NewValues` to the final size of the vector is independent of all of the other entries. You can directly compute that contribution up front in O(1) time with a bit of math

Comment: No there isnt a particular reason for recursion, but if I am correct it doesnt makke a difference and I thought this looked nicer :D

Comment: This post was closed as *opinion-based*. ??? Sorry, I can't understand it. Voting to reopen.

Comment: So I should save the vector size and then build upon that or...?

Comment: This Advent of Code 2021 day 6 ... the solution to it is to it is to not simulate the fish in the direct way; that is, such that you have a data structure that is growing in size with the number of fish. Recognize that all fish with the same number of days remaining are identical and there are only 9 possible values of remaining days, and see if that insight helps you.

Comment: Yh I have a good idea, so do I have to keep a count for the amount of fish that have the same amount of days left. Because otherwise how would I know the total size?

Comment: Its not working for me and its so infuriating, can anyone give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: @Jojo, you have the idea with "so do I have to keep a count for the amount of fish that have the same amount of days left". All you need is an array of nine 64 bit integers representing the counts of fish with days [0,...,8] remaining and you can simulate one day on that and then just repeat 256 times. Make sure all your arithmetic is 64 bit though.

Comment: Yh I get that, but the thing is that my frequency list just wont work, thanks alot tho!

Comment: I mean, I can post code if you want.

Comment: If thats possible, it would be lovely!

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but in that for loop, you know that `l` (horrible variable name, by the way; too easy to mistake for `1`) is a valid index, so you don't need to check it in three different places inside the loop. Just use `NewValues[l]`. –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the number of fish grows exponentially, it is a bad idea to do a simulation that grows in space with the number of fish. We can avoid this by recognizing all fish with the same number of days remaining are identical and that there are only nine possible values, [0, ... , 8], of days remaining for a given fish.

We can thus represent the state of the simulation as an array of nine counts of fish:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <array>

std::string file_to_string(const std::string& filename) {
    std::ifstream file(filename);
    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << file.rdbuf();
    return buffer.str();
}

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& s, char delim) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        elems.push_back(item);
    }
    return elems;
}

std::vector<int> parse_to_ints(const std::string& input) {
    auto num_strs = split(input, ',');
    std::vector<int> nums;
    std::transform(num_strs.begin(), num_strs.end(), std::back_inserter(nums),
        [](const std::string& str)->int {
            return std::stoi(str);
        }
    );
    return nums;
}

class school_o_fish {
private:
    std::array<uint64_t, 9> counts_;
public:
    school_o_fish(const std::vector<int>& initial_pop) {
        counts_ = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };
        for (int days : initial_pop) {
            counts_[days]++;
        }
    }

    void simulate_one_day() {
        auto  reborn = counts_[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
            counts_[i - 1] = counts_[i];
        }
        counts_[8] = reborn;
        counts_[6] += reborn;
    }

    uint64_t total() {
        return std::accumulate(counts_.begin(), counts_.end(), 0ull);
    }

    uint64_t  simulate_n_days(int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            simulate_one_day();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
            std::cout << i << " : " << counts_[i] << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";

        return total();
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "day 6\n\n";

    school_o_fish s(
        parse_to_ints(
            file_to_string("c:\\test\\day6.txt")
        )
    );

    std::cout << s.simulate_n_days(256) << "\n";
}
```

Inverting the simulation like this seems related in spirit to ["the flyweight design pattern"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).

Comment: Jesus did you use make that?? xD
Thanks alot tho!

Comment: oh i mean, i did it last night. I'm doing AoC this year too.

Comment: This is fair out of my code range tho, I just started do you know of any programs with more "understandable" code for me. Only if you have time tho. And do you maybe only have the frequencylist part of the code so I can make the code more my own?

Comment: the school_o_fish class does not have anything tricky in it syntax-wise, just look at that. All the numbers get shifted down one slot in the array and then you take the old zero-day fish and add that on to the new sixes and also copy it into the 8 slot, as it is the new 8 count.